# Can we define $\operatorname{Spec}(H^0(X, \mathcal O_X))$ for a scheme $X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

If $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$, then $H^0(X,\mathcal O_X)=\mathcal O_X(X)=A$ is a ring.

(1) For a general scheme $X$, does the space $H^0(X,\mathcal O_X)$ of global sections of structure sheaf still form a ring? If so, what is $\operatorname{Spec} (H^0(X,\mathcal O_X))$, and how is it related to $X$? Any reference?

(2) Suppose we have several global sections $s_1,\dots, s_m\in H^0(X,\mathcal O_X)$, and consider the ideal $\mathcal I=(s_1,\dots, s_m)$ generated by them. Then, how do we understand $\operatorname{Spec} (H^0(X,\mathcal O_X) /\mathcal I)$? Is it just the base locus of these sections? (If $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$, this is clear. But what if $X$ is a general scheme.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is a ring, because $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a sheaf of rings. The scheme $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is called the *affinization* of $X$, and it's the universal affine scheme to which $X$ maps (this follows from the adjunction between global sections and Spec - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848370/a-scheme-is-affine-iff-the-natural-map-x-to-operatornamespec-gammax-is-an/1848378#1848378) for more details).
2. It's the base locus of those sections on the affinization. The preimage of this under the affinization map is the base locus of the sections $s_i$ on $X$.