# Is base change $X_\mathbb{C}$ of projective variety $X$ over $\mathbb{R}$ a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

On page 10 of the article https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.04806# I found morphismp which behaves on smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{R}$ like $X \mapsto \mathrm{Spec}(H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X))$. In this context this morphism send to $\mathrm{Spec}(H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X))$ only projective varieties over $\mathbb{R}$, on other types it behaves differently. So I need to understand, how it behaives on base changes.

More generaly, consider $X$ to be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{R}$. Under what condition $X_{\mathbb{C}}$ is still smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{R}$?

To be more precise, does the variety remain projective after the change of base?

As example, is base change $E_{\mathbb{C}}$ of elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{R}$ a projective variety over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This situation you're asking about is a little unusual - can you explain why you want to consider the base change as a scheme over $\Bbb R$?

Comment: I need to understand how the map $X\mapsto Spec H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ behaves on smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{R}$. This map is defined only on smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: No, that map is defined on all schemes due to the adjunction between $\operatorname{Spec}$ and global sections; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848370/a-scheme-is-affine-iff-the-natural-map-x-to-operatornamespec-gammax-is-an/1848378#1848378) for more info. (Also, when responding specifically to another user, [@replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) are your friend.)

Comment: @KReiser No, that's not exactly what I meant (sorry for bad English).  Slightly different context.  I found this morphism in this article: https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.04806, page 10.  In short, this morphism acts on generators that are smooth projective over $\mathbb{R}$, I need to understand whether this morphism works the same way on base changes.

Comment: Ah, that's valuable context for your question - please add that to your post with an [edit].

Comment: Do you require a "variety" to be geometrically connected?  If so, this fails even for $X = \mathrm{Spec} \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $X\to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R})$ is smooth, $X_{\mathbb{C}}\to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$ is smooth.

Since $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ is separable, $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C})\to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R})$ is smooth.

In the end, the composition $X_{\mathbb{C}}\to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C})\to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R})$ is smooth.

Comment: But in what condition $X_{\mathbb{C}}$ remains projective over $\mathbb{R}$?